# Process Hacker 2 : How to avoid storing strings on memory during code scan

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, security

We have developed WPF application and we have created the individual config file for the environment. In each config file, we have the data with encrypted format and we used to decrypted the data whenever we need it from the application.

But when we used to run process hacker tool is capturing all the data as plain text. Not sure is there any way we can keep the confidential info and read it proper way, which process hacker will not capture during the code scan.

Comment: Did you take a look at SecureString? It's developed for this purpose. Once the data is decrypted, store it in SecureString instead of String! - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-6.0

Comment: well, if your application is to use the data, then at _some_ point it _has to_ be descrypted. fundamentally, there's nothing you can do about it; so no, you cannot _prevent_ an attacker with sufficient access to read your data. you can only make it harder. and usually, it's not worth the effort. (@CodeNinja _especially_ look at the part that says `We don't recommend that you use the SecureString class for new development`)

Comment: Private keys should never be part of an application distribution.  Private keys should be added to the config file during installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Encrypted strings will be decrypted at runtime at some point. When decrypted, there is no way to hide that string that has been loaded into memory.